# how to easily remove video metadata on Ubuntu 17.10/18.04? (using GUI instead of terminal)

Tags: software-recommendation, files, metadata

In Windows, I can easily removed video metadata by:

1. right clicking on the file/files
2. Select Details tab
3. Click on "Remove properties and personal information"
4. Select "Remove select properties for file"
5. Click "Select all"
6. Click "Ok"

Is there a way to do this easily on Ubuntu/Linux?

At the moment, I wrote a shell script:

1. that uses ffmpeg to strip out all metadata
2. save this to a new file
3. then delete old file
4. then rename new file to old file

Thanks

Comment: Please define "easily". Also, what is wrong with that "at the moment" solution?

Comment: @mikewhatever point and click vs running a script in terminal? I'll take point and click :)

Comment: I think this is clear and I don't support closing it. However, can you **[edit]** your question to state what desktop environment you're using? This is relevant because you want to right-click on a file icon and get a menu item, but the contextual menu raised when you right-click an icon varies across file browsers, and each desktop environment (pretty much) has its own file browser. Or you could just say what file browser you are using. For example, is it Nautilus ("Files")? Also, would a menu item that runs your script work? Also, can you include the contents of your script in the question?

Comment: @EliahKagan Added the distro I've tried/using

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shell script based on the current solution and create one or more file associations for it.

### Shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
ffmpeg -i "$1" ... "$1~"  # Replace the dots with your FFmpeg options
mv -T -- "$1~" "$1"
```

Save the script in a file and add executable permissions.

### File association

See [How to add a custom program to “Open With” list of programs in Xubuntu 13.04? How to associate a file with a program to open it with?](/q/317392/175814) (Despite the question title the answers cover all desktop environments that support the Freedesktop specification which means all major ones including GNOME and Unity.)